# Trying to capture Bluetooth Low enerygy HCI Data packets

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, packet-capture, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have set up a Network where two devices are exchanging Bluetooth LE data.

The problem is when I use Wireshark I cannot see any HCI data packets. All I can see is HCI command packets and HCI event packets. When I use hcidump in Kali linux I get the same outcome.

I have seen examples online where HCI data packets appear when using hcidump. Can anyone suggest why I am not seeing any HCI data packets even though I am definitely sending data between the devices?

Comment: Have you tried the btmon command instead? It works better for me than hcidump.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all HCI packets, including ACL data packets, you must run `hcidump` or `btmon` as root.

Try `sudo hcidump`